# Rectangle Class Java

Tags: java

Ok this is homework.  I can't for life of me figure out what I am doing wrong here.  From the book "The set methods should verify that length and width are each floating-point numbers larger than 0.0 and less than 20.0"  I thought I had it but when I run my test it just gives me the area and perimeter.

```
public class Rectangle {
private float width = 1;
private float length = 1;

public Rectangle(float userWidth, float userLength) {
    width = userWidth;
    length = userLength;

}

public void setWidth(float userWidth) {
    if (userWidth < 0.0 || userWidth > 20.0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(Float.toString(width));
    } else {
        width = userWidth;
    }
}

public float getWidth() {
    return width;

}

public void setLength(float userLength) {
    if (userLength < 0.0 || userLength > 20.0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(Float.toString(length));
    } else {
        length = userLength;
    }
}

public float getLength() {
    return length;
}

public float calcArea() {
    return length * width;
}

public float calcPerimeter() {
    return length + length + width + width;
}

}
```

And my test code is

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class RectangleTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the width");
    float width = input.nextFloat();

    System.out.println("Enter the length");
    float length = input.nextFloat();

    Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(width, length);

    System.out.printf("The area is: %.2f\n", myRectangle.calcArea());
    System.out.printf("The perimeter is: %.2f\n",
            myRectangle.calcPerimeter());

    input.close();

}

}
```

Comment: You're not verifying the values in the constructor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use your `Rectangle(float, float)` constructor you aren't using your mutator methods to perform validation. You could do something like

```
public Rectangle(float userWidth, float userLength) {
    // width = userWidth;
    // length = userLength;
    setWidth(userWidth);
    setLength(userLength);
}
```

which would invoke your "setters". Also, there is a subtle (and only potential) bug hiding in

```
input.close();
```

because `System.in` is a global variable you might experience unexpected behavior if you extract your code into a method (and then attempt to read from `System.in` anywhere else).

Comment: No, not at all @Spidey. Constructors are to be used to only initialise values. Check my answer.

Comment: @shekharsuman That's arguable, but I agree it should be avoided.  In you answer, you should get rid of the constructor parameters altogether, as they are introducing confusion into the proper usage of the class

Comment: I remember that in class.  I knew there had to be something simple.  This is the way we did it in another program.

Comment: @MadProgrammer- I probably commented about the same, and I myself forgot to include that. Anyways, thanks. I have attributed your name in my answer for helping. THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

You should look here :

```
public Rectangle(float userWidth, float userLength) {
width = userWidth;
length = userLength;
```

}

The values have been assigned without verifying. May be use your set method here in constructor. This will throw an exception when you are assigning illegal arguments.